# jQuery fadeIn displaying too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am doing an ajax call with wordpress, when the ajax call is complete I fade out the div slowly (works perfectly) I then try to fade in the new data, I am currently using the jquery method fadeIn(). Whatever number or speed I put into the method doesn't seem to have an effect on the speed, not even something huge like 6000 milliseconds.

Can anyone see why? Heres my code.

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

    jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').fadeOut('2000', function() {
        jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').replaceWith(response);
        jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').fadeIn('6000');
});
```

Comment: what is coming in the response?

Comment: Doesn't `replaceWith` nuke your `#mc_embed_signup`? So the second selector doesn't find anything and the new content shows up immediately because it isn't hidden.

Comment: Don't put the numbers in the quotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As IrkenInvader pointed out in his comment, you will lose the reference to your element with the id when its replaced.

You may want to wrap your container which you want to replace in another container and fade in / out this wrapping container like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">...</div>
</div>

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    jQuery('#wrapper').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').replaceWith(response);
        jQuery('#wrapper').fadeIn(6000);
    });
});
```

Additionally, like Asad provided with his answer, `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()` accepts only numbers (time in milliseconds) or a string with the actual name of the speed like `slow` or `fast`.

It's also worth mentioning, that these methods accept an options object as well which provides a lot of methods and properties:

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: `you will lose the reference to your element with the id when its replaced.` No. you are not. Read it [here](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

Comment: Yes it does. `replaceWith` RETURNS the object, so when you chain another function on it, you can use that "old" object. But in his case he already ended the function call and tried to select the element which is not longer accessible with the id as a selector.

Answer (score 2):

You have to hide the replaced content first and fade it in,

```
var replacedElem = null;
jQuery('#mc_embed_signup').replaceWith((replacedElem  = $(response).hide(),replacedElem));
replacedElem.fadeIn(6000);
```

You are wrongly selecting the element. You have to cache the element that is going to be replaced and manipulate it for your requirement. That is hiding and fading it in.

### [Procedural demo](https://jsfiddle.net/utfjby1e/)

***why do i need to cache the element that is used for replacement?*** must be your question.

Answer is, [Document](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) is saying so.

> The .replaceWith() method, like most jQuery methods, returns the
>   jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However,
>   it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This
>   object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not
>   the new element that has replaced it.

So we cannot chain the newly replaced element. we have to store it somewhere before using it.

Answer (score 0):

give it only 600 not '600'.
it accepts integer value like 600 not a string like '600' . 
Or you can give

```
 .fadeIn('fast')
```

or

```
  fadeIn('slow') like this
```